# Como ler esse exemplo de Json corretamente?

Tags: php, json

estou tende dificuldade de ler esse Json, pois ele tem, em alguns retornos, vários endereços, imagem exemplo abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em fim, alguem pode me ajudar?, necessito carregar o ou os AddressMain, destaquei na imagem acima.

Caminhos: 
object->Result->0->CreditData->0->Addresses->0->AddressMain
object->Result->0->CreditData->0->Addresses->1->AddressMain

Como montei o meu código:

```html
<?php

$json_data = json_decode(file_get_contents('arquivo2.json'));

foreach ($json_data->Result-> as $data) {
    echo '<br>País: ' .$data->CreditData-> ->Addresses-> ->Country;
    echo '<br>';

}
?>
```

Meu erro esta no "caminho" os "0", "1" estão me quebrando... se alguem puder me dar uma dica eu agradeço

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O JSON retorna vários [array's](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.array.php), e address é mais uma delas.
Você pode fazer um foreach nessa array ou então optar sempre por acessar o primeiro índice, seu código ficaria assim:

```
<?php

$json_data = json_decode(file_get_contents('arquivo2.json'), true);

foreach ($json_data["Result"] as $data) {
    echo '<br>País: ' .$data["CreditData"][0]["Addresses"][0]["Country"];
    echo '<br>';

}
?>
```

Passe também o parâmetro assoc como true na função [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-decode.php) para converter para um array associativo.

Comment: Paulo, tentei mas não funcionou ... deu erro

Comment: Qual o erro retornado? Pode fornecer o json também?

Comment: Retorno esse erro:

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\Docker\www\index3.php on line 5
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0030 361968 {main}( ) ...\index3.php:0

Comment: Pelo visto o json_decode não está retornando um array, você adicionou o parâmetro true?

Comment: sim ... parâmetro esta true

Comment: Pode fornecer o json para eu verificar o erro?

Comment: Paulo, consegui ... o erra era result e tem de ser Result... mas sigo com um problema ainda ele segue carregando somente um dos endereço, ele não carrega o segundo de forma "automática"...

Comment: @PauloVictor está faltando um segundo loop dentro do foreach para pegar os valores das chaves ..................... `[0]["Country"]`... `[1]["Country"]`.. e assim por diante.

Comment: Como falei, ele tem a opção de usar a primeira entrada ou fazer um outro loop, dei apenas um exemplo.

Comment: Paulo Victor tem como entrar em contato com você?