# Como colocar loop para carregar resultado do Json

Tags: php, json, loop

Pessoal to precisando de uma ajuda, to carregando umas informações do Json, como segue abaixo:

```html
<?php

$json_data = json_decode(file_get_contents('arquivo3.json'), true);

foreach ($json_data["Result"] as $data) {

 
 echo '<br>Endereço: ' .$data["CreditData"][0]["Addresses"][0]["AddressMain"];
 echo '<br>Número: ' .$data["CreditData"][0]["Addresses"][0]["Number"];
 echo '<br>Complemento: ' .$data["CreditData"][0]["Addresses"][0]["Complement"];
 echo '<br>Cidade: ' .$data["CreditData"][0]["Addresses"][0]["City"];
 echo '<br>CEP: ' .$data["CreditData"][0]["Addresses"][0]["ZipCode"];
 echo '<br>Familiar: ' .$data["CreditData"][0]["Addresses"][0]["Neighborhood"];
 echo '<br>Estado: ' .$data["CreditData"][0]["Addresses"][0]["State"];
 echo '<br>País: ' .$data["CreditData"][0]["Addresses"][0]["Country"];
 
    echo '<br>';
 
// NÃO QUERIA REPETIR A LINHA ABAIXO E COLOCAR AQUI UM LOOP PARA AUTOMATICAMENTE CARREGAR QUANTO FOR NECESSÁRIOS DE ENDEREÇOS

 echo '<br>Endereço: ' .$data["CreditData"][0]["Addresses"][1]["AddressMain"];
 echo '<br>Número: ' .$data["CreditData"][0]["Addresses"][1]["Number"];
 echo '<br>Complemento: ' .$data["CreditData"][0]["Addresses"][1]["Complement"];
 echo '<br>Cidade: ' .$data["CreditData"][0]["Addresses"][1]["City"];
 echo '<br>CEP: ' .$data["CreditData"][0]["Addresses"][1]["ZipCode"];
 echo '<br>Familiar: ' .$data["CreditData"][0]["Addresses"][1]["Neighborhood"];
 echo '<br>Estado: ' .$data["CreditData"][0]["Addresses"][1]["State"];
 echo '<br>País: ' .$data["CreditData"][0]["Addresses"][1]["Country"];
 
    echo '<br>';

}
?>
```

PERGUNTO:

Como pode observar necessito que ele traga o endereço de determinada pessoa, porem algumas pessoas tem mais de 1 endereço cadastrado, dai ele poder trazer 1 ou 2 ou até mais de 5 endereços diferentes. Como faço para criar um loop para que não tenha de ficar repetindo as linhas?

Comment: Dejavu -> https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/371710/como-ler-esse-exemplo-de-json-corretamente/371711

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você já está utilizando um loop, não está? Não basta aninhar outro loop dentro dele?

```
foreach ($json_data["Result"] as $data) {
    foreach ($data["CreditData"][0]["Addresses"] as $address) {

        echo '<br>Endereço: ' .$address["AddressMain"];
        echo '<br>Número: ' .$address["Number"];
        echo '<br>Complemento: ' .$address["Complement"];
        echo '<br>Cidade: ' .$address["City"];
        echo '<br>CEP: ' .$address["ZipCode"];
        echo '<br>Familiar: ' .$address["Neighborhood"];
        echo '<br>Estado: ' .$address["State"];
        echo '<br>País: ' .$address["Country"];

        echo '<br>';
    }
}
```